# Pasting in images

Tags: support, images

Could people please tell me some of the more common ways to place/paste images, rather than links to images, in an answer on Main? Last night I requested an image from Joseph O'Rourke, who is a helpful fellow. I ran the mouse from corner to corner, then pasted that into an answer box for [a big number that is obviously prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148852/a-big-number-that-is-obviously-prime) . The result is not the image, rather a big URL that appears to have something to do with the nature of the image as an email attachment. If you (I) click on it, the image does appear as I want it.

The more intricate item was several days ago, [Another quadratic Diophantine equation: How do I proceed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794)   where I had deleted my answer owing to the OP considering it too difficult and worthless and me not wanting to deal with that. I got email from a moderator saying there had been a request for re-instatement. I realized the one chance for it to make sense was to draw the diagram myself, so I scanned it in and asked Joseph to place my diagram in the middle of my answer, which he did very well. With the diagram, my answer is not over anyone's head.

I will read some of the "Similar Questions" I currently see as links on the right side of my screen. If someone could fix the image at  [Another quadratic Diophantine equation: How do I proceed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794) that would be great, although I ought also to learn how to do this. After all, "Give a man a fire and he's warm for a night. Set fire to him and he's warm for the rest of his life."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the image upload function provided by the editor. It is the sixth button from the left above the textbox when you compose an answer.

Click on it. Follow the instructions.

Comment: Oh, you got your image from google mail. You will need to download it first and save it as a local copy. (In Gmail, click "Download" and save it somewhere on your harddrive.) Then in the dialog that comes up with the image upload button, find the path for that saved copy. Now it will be uploaded to StackExchange's image hosting service, and you can delete your local copy if you want.

Comment: (BTW, you may want to mark that answer Community Wiki. I think some downvotes may be heading your way for that [admittedly funny] answer.)

Comment: Willie, apparently I did the right steps. I saved a copy on a directory on my home computer. It said it was locked, when I said ls-l | grep Big it said -r------ and so on, so I said chmod 644 image.png which may or may not have been necessary. then I went to the sixth icon from the left, clicked on that, clicked again to Browse, and chose from that directory. It seems to be working now. I think it is time to buy a home scanner that can, at least, make a black-and-white pdf out of a single page. I could have drawn this image last night with an oversized marker.

Comment: Thanks for the CW warning. Let me say here that this is from The Phantom Tollbooth by Norton Juster, illustrations by Jules Feiffer, page 189: http://books.google.com/books?id=kxcXm_Q9csEC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=phantom+tollbooth+%22inside+was+the+biggest+3+Milo+had+ever+seen%22&source=bl&ots=9Di4nzAL6g&sig=1IrohSRdXozH4n7xvwfFibTunVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o5O9T6jhLoqhiALnp8SgDg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Mathematicians are strange about humor. Even when they're doing something funny, they look ashamed, as if they're afraid someone might catch them at it.